# delete character of 2 string to make them anagram in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, anagram

I tried to solve one of the Hackerrank challenges String: Making Anagrams

I have 2 strings like this:

```
let a: string = "fcrxzwscanmligyxyvym"
let b: string = "jxwtrhvujlmrpdoqbisbwhmgpmeoke"
```

and I have a function that only passed 3 tests!!! :

```
function makeAnagram(a: string, b: string): number {
    type Map = {
        [key :string] : number
    }
   let string1 = a.split('')
   let string2 = b.split('')
   let map : Map = {}
   let deletedCount = 0
   let firstCount = 0
   let isMoreThanTwo = false
   
   for(let i of string1) {
       map[i] = (map[i] | 0) + 1
   }
   
   for(let i of string2){
       map[i] = (map[i] | 0) + 1
   }
   
   for(let i in map) {
       if(map[i] == 1) {
           deletedCount++
           firstCount++
       } else if(map[i] > 2) {
           isMoreThanTwo = true
           deletedCount += (map[i] - 1)
       }
       
   }
   
   return isMoreThanTwo ? deletedCount + firstCount : deletedCount
```

is there any other solution to count deleted characters? and can you guys give me some advice, thank you

Comment: Isn't this a leetcode question? haha Modern problems require modern solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just solved this problem but before passing all test cases I came to a solution where I used

```
for (let [k, v] of map) {
  remain += v;
}
```

which failed `13/16` test cases, then I debugged the program and came to know that sometimes when we subtract `1` from the previous of this step, It goes `less than 0` so Yo also have to handle this case, I handles as

```
for (let [k, v] of map) {
  remain += v < 0 ? v * -1 : v;
}
```

[**Now, all test cases are passed**](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-making-anagrams/forum/comments/1056389)

```js
function makeAnagram(a, b) {
  const [small, big] = a.length < b.length ? [a, b] : [b, a];
  const map = new Map();
  for (let c of small) {
    map.set(c, (map.get(c) ?? 0) + 1);
  }

  let remain = 0;
  for (let c of big) {
    !map.has(c) ? remain++ : map.set(c, map.get(c) - 1);
  }

  for (let [k, v] of map) {
    remain += v < 0 ? v * -1 : v;
  }

  return remain;
}

console.log(makeAnagram("fast", "sofasty"));
```